# imagick creates wrong colorspace / colors

Tags: colors, imagick

I have the following code on my site where i have to create images out of uploaded pdf files, my problem is that i cannot get the colors right (and yes there can be both text and images in the pdf files):

```
        $img = new imagick();
        $img->setResolution(72, 72);
        $img->readImage($dir_f.$file);
        $img->set ImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_NO);
        $img->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

        $num_pages = $img->getNumberImages();
        for($i = 0;$i < $num_pages; $i++) {
            $fina l_name     = str_replace(" ", "+", basename(str_replace(".".$file_ext,"", $file_name)));
            $final_name     = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-+]/", "", $final_name);

            $save_to        = $pdf_dir."/".str_replace(".".$file_ext,"", $final_name).'-'.$i.'.png';

            $img->setIteratorIndex($i);
            $img->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_NO);
            $img->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
            $img->setimageformat("png");
            $img->writeImage($save_to);

            $file_image = str_replace(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../", "/", $save_to);
            $file_images[] = array($file_image, $index[$ii]);
        }
        $img->destroy();
```

I have gotten different results depending on wich type of colorspace i have been using but non of them are correctly made colors.

when i dont set a colorspace it gets to bright.
when i use colorspace srgb or cmyk the image gets to bright,
when i use colorspace COMPRESSION_NO it gets to bright
when i use colorspace rgb it gets to dark

Hopefully someone is able to help me out here.

Comment: "Imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick library. Please upload example images to imgur.com (or other site) if your question is asking why Imagick is not producing the images you are expecting," A source PDF wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/oIk0b

The first image is the one created with imagemagick
The second one is the original pdf page.

Comment: Ok I can see a different, but without a source PDF it's hard to investigate. You could try setting the colorspace and then transforming it, to adjust the color, but that is a shot in the dark `$imagick->setImageColorSpace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB); $imagick->transofrmImageColorSpace(imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);` which might 'fix' the color.

Comment: That seemed to invert the colors when i added it here:
    
   $img->setIteratorIndex($i);
       $img->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_NO);
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
    $img->setImageColorSpace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
    $img->transformImageColorSpace(imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
    $img->setimageformat("png");
       $img->writeImage($save_to);

the source PDf is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zlwwn394kixhiw/153311-flyers-sample-papers-volume-2.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's a bug in Ghostscript, which is the delegate program ImageMagick normally uses to convert PDFs to bitmap format.

Using Ghostscript version 8.70 I see the same output you are seeing, i.e. the image is lighter than it is when viewing the PDF directly.

After downloading [Ghostscript version 9](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and running the command below to do the conversion, I see the same colours as in the PDF.

You're probably going to need to either upgrade to Ghostscript 9 or figure out what is special about the PDF that makes Ghostscript not convert it correctly. I think the PDF might either have a non-standard color profile or weird colorspace. But as converting it with GS9 works fine, that is probably the easiest way to fix the problem.

```
./ghostscript-9.16-linux-x86_64/gs-916-linux_x86_64 -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH \
  -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 \
  -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=1 -sDEVICE=pngalpha \
  -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=3 \
  -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72 \
  -sOutputFile=gs-%d.png 153311-flyers-sample-papers-volume-2.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Ill try pass this on to person controlling the server enviorment.